# Sorting Table with represent symbol

Tags: javascript, html

I had a sorting function code like below. I would like to create an arrow up (data in ascending order) or arrow bottom (data in descending order) at right side of the  field when clicked. Please advise. Thanks

Example field:

[image: sorting.png]

```js
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function () {makeAllSortable();};
```

```css
table {width: 100%;font: 12px arial;}
th, td {min-width: 40px;text-align: center;}
th {font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>c1</th>
      <th>c2</th>
      <th>c3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td><td>t</td><td>p</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td><td>v</td><td>r</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>f</td><td>a</td><td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>h</td><td>t</td><td>i</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/).

- Include [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/) to your project
- Add id and icon to your `<th>` like this:

`<th id="sort-col-1">c1<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></th>`

- Add js code to switch icons on click.

```
$("#sort-col-1").on("click", function(){
  var icon = $(this).find(".glyphicon");
  if(icon.hasClass("glyphicon-sort-by-attributes")){
    icon.removeClass("glyphicon-sort-by-attributes");
    icon.addClass("glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt");
  }
  else{
    icon.removeClass("glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt");
    icon.addClass("glyphicon-sort-by-attributes");
  }
});
```

Optionally you can switch to other icons not especially from Bootstrap, important part is code to switch them when clicked.

[Example in js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtqm2vk8/)